# Are short task (100ms - 10s) less optimized than median task in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

If my task is 100ms - 5s range , does the overhead of spawning these task creates less efficiency compare to task that finish in 1-5min range?

For example all else equal is it better efficiency wise to have task finish around minute range?

The official doc says that

> Spark can efficiently support tasks as short as 200 ms, because it reuses one executor JVM across many tasks and it has a low task launching cost, so you can safely increase the level of parallelism to more than the number of cores in your clusters.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html

Which seem to indicate that it doesn't matter if the task size is small